# wordpress's dbDelta function stopped working

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin which requires database interactivity. I am using the dbDelta function in my activate hook to add several tables to the database. The `dbDelta` function *was* working last week, but when I went to add another table today nothing happened. I was not able to add columns or change attributes of existing tables either. Someone suggested breaking up the sql commands before running dbDelta, but this does not work either.

Before you ask: yes, I have read the codex page and followed the formatting instructions.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function install ()
{

    global $wpdb; //use the global variable wpdb, a class used to interact with wordpress's database

    //define table names, using the the db's prefix
    $gist_table = $wpdb->prefix . "cookbook_gist";
    $tag_table = $wpdb->prefix . "cookbook_tags";
    $tagKey_table = $wpdb->prefix . "cookbook_tagKeys";
    $comment_table = $wpdb->prefix . "cookbook_comments";
    $blacklist_table = $wpdb->prefix . "cookbook_blacklist";

   //Include the wpdb function

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php'); //the dbDelta function is in this file

    //create the sql statements to add the tables

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $gist_table (
    gist_id mediumint NOT NULL,
    last_cached datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    last_updated datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    author tinytext NOT NULL,
    description mediumtext NOT NULL,
    header mediumtext NOT NULL,
    body text NOT NULL,
    footer mediumtext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (gist_id)
    );";

    //Actually add the table
    dbDelta($sql);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tag_table (
    tag_id mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tag tinytext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (tag_id)
    );";

    dbDelta($sql);

    $sql ="CREATE TABLE $tagKey_table (
    id mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    gist_id mediumint NOT NULL,
    tag_id mediumint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );";

    dbDelta($sql);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $comment_table (
    id mediumint NOT NULL,
    gist_id mediumint NOT NULL,
    author tinytext NOT NULL,
    date_created datetime NOT NULL,
    comment mediumtext NOT NULL,
    newcol text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );";

    dbDelta($sql);


    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $blacklist_table (
    gist_id mediumint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (gist_id)
    );";


    dbDelta($sql); //makes the changes to the wp database    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. A few days ago my hosting service changed the server we were hosted on; and I was still logging on to the old server to administer the database. When I logged onto the correct server, the changes had been made as expected.